# issue related to splitting string by whitespace

Tags: c++

i am currently making a "stack-based programming language" where in order to push a string onto the stack, you shall use **"** at the beggining on the string, and also on the end. So in the end an acceptable string is something like this: **"some_string"**.

However, i need to tokenize the whole line of the file i am reading (splitting by whitespaces).
This means i cant use such string: **"hello are you there?"** because it would get splitten up into **"hello** (new element) **are** (new element) **you** (new element) **there?"**. And this is a problem because i want it to be a whole element, not four separated elements (since texts that are not beggining with a " are treated as keywords, and it would lead to a keyword not found error because i dont have the keyword yes).

This is my current code (where str should be the line i am reading from the file, and the delimiter is a simple whitespace, ' '):

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize(std::string str, char delim) {
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::vector<std::string> out;

    std::string s;
    while (std::getline(ss, s, delim)) {
        s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '\t'), s.end());
        out.push_back(s);
    }

    return out; }
```

What approach shall i take?

Comment: I think you should have a dedicated tokenizer for this. As you have observerd you need something smarter than just splitting on whitespace. I would suggest a simple tokenizer which goes through the input **stream** one character at a time. Then you can track whether you are inside or outside of quotes and emit appropriate tokens. Same goes for line detection or finding comments. Basic ones could be SYMBOL NUMBER STRING_LITERAL COMMENT NEWLINE.

Comment: Then you might need to consider, too, embedded quotes – you might need some kind of escaping.

Comment: @Quimby I have a dedicated tokenizer which checks char by char, and i pass each element of the string vector to it.

Comment: If you know where the quoted string appears, you can read it in one piece using [std::quoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted)

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain English. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: @st3ph4nnnn What is a string vector? Is it per-file per-line or whitespace-separated?

Answer (score 0):

`std::quoted` will be your friend. Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) about it.

Then your task will be as simple as the below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::string test{ "abc  \t def \"ghi jk\"\t  lmn\top\n" };

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string& s) {

    std::istringstream iss(s);

    std::string part{};
    std::vector<std::string> result{};

    while (iss >> std::quoted(part))
        result.push_back(std::move(part));

    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto parts = split(test);
    for (const auto& part : parts)
        std::cout << part << '\n';
}
```